# Skipping line intermittently in Python

Tags: python

Given these data

```
Probes  FOO BAR
Organ   BM LV
Genes   Gene1 Gene2
1452463_x_at    306.564     185.705 
1439374_x_at    393.742     330.495 
1426392_a_at    269.850     209.931
```

I want to skip printing first two lines that starts with Organs and Genes.
What I tried to do is this:

```
with open('my_data.txt','r') as tsvfile
    tabreader = csv.reader(tsvfile,delimiter = '\t')

    for row in tabreader:
        if ["Genes","Organ"] in row:
            continue
        print row
```

But why it failed?

The final desired output is this:

```
Probes  FOO BAR
1452463_x_at    306.564     185.705 
1439374_x_at    393.742     330.495 
1426392_a_at    269.850     209.931
```

Comment: In Python, it is easier to just negaate the statement with the `not` function. For example, you might consider using the expression: `if row[0] not in ('Genes', 'Organ'): print row`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why it failed?

Because you check, whether `["Genes", "Organ"]` is in row (which it is not, because you check a list of single elements for the existence of a two element sublist), whereas you might want to frame it the other way:

```
# row[0] is a single element ...
# .. that might be in ("Genes", "Organ")
if row[0] in ("Genes", "Organ"):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if "Genes" in row or "Organ" in row
```

Should do the trick!

Your mistake was to assume that table+table operator behave same as object+table. Watch out for such.